# How to get post pagination like this

Tags: pagination

I'm using this function right now

```
wp_link_pages( array('before' => '<div class="page-links">','after'  => '</div>',) );
```

The post pagination is showing like this:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

But I want it to be like this in that there's too many pages

> 1 2 3 ..9 10 11

However, There's no `mid_size` or `end_size` like function `paginate_links()`

I've been searching for answer all day, Is there anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with `wp_link_pages()`, but you can use `paginate_links()`. You just need to configure the arguments so that the links are based on the pagination of your post/page. To do this you just need to know:

- The base URL. This is the permalink of the page/post.
- The format of the pagination portion of the URL. This is just the page number, like `/6`, and not `/page/6` or `/?page=5` or anything like that.
- The total number of pages. This is the global `$numpages` variable.
- The current page. This is the global `$page` variable.

Which you can use like this:

```
echo paginate_links(
    [
        'base'    => user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( get_the_permalink() ) . '%_%' ),
        'format'  => '%#%',
        'total'   => $numpages,
        'current' => $page,
    ]
);
```

Note that we want `base` to be something like this, where `%_%` is where our page number will go:

```
http://website.test/2021/03/25/my-post/%_%/
```

To do this properly we use `trailingslashit()` on `get_the_permalink()` to guarantee that there is a slash between the URL and the placeholder. Then we use `user_trailingslashit()` to add a trailing slash to the very end in case the site is configured that way.

Comment: Would this change the pagination to use `1,2,3,....8,9,10` though? I don't think the OP wants to change the URL

Comment: Yes it would, and it’s not changing the URL.

Comment: I've re-read the answer and I don't understand how it achieves the OP's desired output, or what base URLs have to do with it. I think there's an important piece of information you've assumed is obvious that is not.

Comment: What aren’t you getting? OP is using wp_link_pages, which is to show page links when using `<!--nextpage-->`. They want to use the features of `paginate_links()`. This code shows how you can use `paginate_links()` for `<!--nextpage-->` pagination.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but It's not working.Maybe is because my post URL is like this  http://example.com/story/10981/page-2.html
http://example.com/story/10981/page-3.html

Comment: How did you achieve that? Are you using `<!--nextpage-->`? Does `wp_link_pages()` work?

Comment: wp_link_pages() works fine.I'm using <!--nextpage--> as well. I've rewrite the pagination URLs otherwise it's like example.com/story/10981/.html/2

Answer (score 0):

Jacob is right that you need to incorporate the function of paginate_links() but I would suggest looking at the examples on this page:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/

My Theme (the amazing MHMagazine Theme) has this function built in and this is how they do it (it does exactly as OP wants, a few digits, an ellipsis, a few more digits, and right or left arrows as needed):

```
if (!function_exists('mh_magazine_pagination')) {
function mh_magazine_pagination() {
    if (get_the_posts_pagination()) {
        echo '<div class="mh-loop-pagination clearfix">';
            the_posts_pagination(array(
                'mid_size' => 1,
                'prev_text' => esc_html__('&laquo;', 'mh-magazine'),
                'next_text' => esc_html__('&raquo;', 'mh-magazine'),
            ));
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
}
```

You can see an example of this in action at this page (scroll to bottom):

https://www.bestallinclusive.com/category/insider-tips/

(Mods, it's okay to delete that last link if not allowed, but I think this does exactly what OP wants so thought he'd like to see it to be sure before trying to implement this).